# unable to run react.net in 64-bit mode on iis

Tags: c#, reactjs, iis

I have followed http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html to get started with ReactJS.
The first step works fine running in `IISExpress`. However running the same example in "real" IIS does not work. I Get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Unable to resolve type: React.Web.IJsxHandler
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request.   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable
>   to resolve type: React.Web.IJsxHandler
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>        Stack Trace:  [TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.Web.IJsxHandler]
>   React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration
>   registration,     NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions
>   options) +1165 React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve() +163
>   React.Web.JsxHandlerFactory.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +52
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +913 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

If I set the "Enable 32-bit applications" setting to `true` in the application pool, the solution starts to work.

Based on this, I guess the problem is related to instantiating the 64-bit react `dll` (or v8 component).
I have tried installing the x64 run time components (both 2012 and 2013) to no avail.